# More than a couple of couplets

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Here's my first attempt at a puzzle:

A

> My 11 from 12 sealed Atalanta's fate
>
> But what did my 7 expect me to crate?

B

> With a merged name between us and unusual style
>
> We have twice tried to win for the Emerald Isle.

C

> Commonly seen in a number of sports
>
> Frequently 3 can be worn in support.

D

> Well defended from predators except when I roam
>
> From second-hand home to second-hand home.

E

> There's nothing from nothing and nobody's out
>
> Other than those when we last swapped about.

F

> When cannons appeared we were quickly retired,
>
> But the force like to use us where force is required.

G

> Between Shakespeare and Sauce for 65 years
>
> Our voices are heard by myriad ears.

H

> Digitless pets and fodder alike
>
> Beware where you crawl for some of us bite.

I

> A means of propulsion for a friend of the hulk
>
> If someone gets yours you are likely to sulk.

J

> No further than Sheppey can our like be found
>
> As our 4 pairs of legs like the warmest of ground.

K

> How big or how heavy? On the hull of a boat
>
> Sometimes reptilian we hold all your notes.

Questions

> **Which one is missing, which name will you try**
>
> **And which of the 8 calls us home this July?**

Comment: I'm completely lost on how 11 of 12 could be golden apples or sex in a temple. Maybe I'm reading too much into it. Nice riddles!

Comment: You're on the right track. Sometimes things crop up more than once in mythology.

Comment: Right, the twelve labors. In which case you're probably talking about the Cretan Bull, unless you're accounting for the second and fifth trials being revoked, in which case you're looking for the girdle of Hippolyta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So with a little help from some friends in the comments, we have the theme and the answers to the couplets.

But still not **which of the 8 calls us home this July?** Any ideas? And why 8 and not 11 or more?

The couplets refer to

> 11 of the 12 signs of the Zodiac. But there are only 11 couplets, and the missing sign is Aquarius (the water carrier).

A

My 11 from 12 sealed Atalanta's fate

But what did my 7 expect me to crate?

> Taurus (the bull). As explained by Kingrames, The 11th labour of Hercules was to steal the Apples of the Hesperides, which were later used by a suitor of Atalanta to beat her in a race and force her hand in marriage. The 7th labour was the Cretan **Bull**

B

With a merged name between us and unusual style

We have twice tried to win for the Emerald Isle.

> Gemini (the twins), with a reference to Jedward, twins who represented Ireland in Eurovision twice.

C

Commonly seen in a number of sports

Frequently 3 can be worn in support.

> Leo (the lion). As in Detroit Lions, or the British and Irish Lions. England supporters wear three lions on their shirt.

D:

Well defended from predators except when I roam

From second-hand home to second-hand home.

> This is Cancer (the crab)

E

There's nothing from nothing and nobody's out

Other than those when we last swapped about.

> This is Virgo, the maiden. In cricket, a maiden over is one where no runs are scored, and also no wickets taken (otherwise it would be a wicket maiden). At the end of each over the fielding team has to swap bowlers (credit to @f'')

F:

When cannons appeared we were quickly retired,

But the force like to use us where force is required.

> This is Aries (the ram). Cannons replaced Rams as a siege weapon, and the police use a ram (thanks to APrough)

G

Between Shakespeare and Sauce for 65 years

Our voices are heard by myriad ears.

> This is Sagittarius, the Archer. The Archers is a BBC radio soap opera, whose Pilot episode was broadcast in 1950. The series takes place in the fictional county of Borsetshire, which (according to wikipedia) is situated between the (in reality contiguous) counties of Worcestershire and Warwickshire. The town of Worcestor is famed for it's sauce, and Stratford-upon-Avon is in Warwickshire (thanks to @Going Hamateur for the tip)

H

Digitless pets and fodder alike

Beware where you crawl for some of us bite.

> This is Pisces (Fish)

I

A means of propulsion for a friend of the hulk

If someone gets yours you are likely to sulk.

> This is Capricorn, the goat. Somebody can "Get your goat". The friend of the hulk is Thor, who has a chariot pulled by war goats (thanks to @Bishop)

J

No further than Sheppey can our like be found

As our 4 pairs of legs like the warmest of ground.

> This should be Scorpio (the Scorpion) which has 8 legs and likes warm climates. According to wikipedia "The isle [of Sheppey] is noted as the northern-most place to have an established scorpion population".

K

How big or how heavy? On the hull of a boat

Sometimes reptilian we hold all your notes.

> This is Libra (the Scales). Scales can weigh, reptiles have scales and there are musical scales.

Comment: The theme is correct, although a few of your answers have not identified the correct signs. I'll leave it a little while before pointing out which ones are right.

Comment: @Kingrames has already identified the correct answer for "A". Archers were made obsolete by small arms rather than cannons, though they were originally called hand cannons.

Comment: The friend of the hulk is Thor, who has a chariot pulled by war goats

Comment: F should be the Ram.  Police often use a ram when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. If anyone gets the last 2 (or maybe more thanks to my muddles?), and the explanation with 8 feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: E sounds like it should be Virgo, perhaps referring to a "maiden over" in cricket, when no runs are scored.

Comment: @f'' is correct too, leaving G (which is easier for people in the UK) and the answers to the questions.

Comment: "Between Shakespeare and Sauce for 65 years" = quick search for Shakespeare 1950 (65 years ago) turns up a bunch of fishing reels. Maybe that leads to Aquarius? Water is between the fishing reel and a fish sauce :) Running water is often said to have "voices". This seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Duncan: it was a bit of a stretch. I'm pretty sure of G now, but can't connect it to Shakespeare or Sauce.

Comment: as for the answer, Cancer is July (mostly) and whichever is missing depends on if all the answers are correct (Personally only G seems a bit off not sure about that one)

Comment: For G I believe this is referring to the rivers avon (stratford upon avon Shakespeare's home town) and the river severn which appears to be related to worcestershire sauce.

Comment: @Going hamateur. Thanks, that sounds about right. I was stuck with HP for the sauce.

Comment: @Spacemonkey. I'm pretty confident on G, especially after Going hamateur's comment. It fits with being a clue easier in  the UK too. Still not sure about the 8 and July. Why 8? 8 planets? Would fit a bit with the astrological theme, but doesn't seem quite to match.

Comment: All right so far and you were on the right track with the 8.